# Single post advertsiements displayed on main page too

Tags: php, css, wordpress, content-management-system

I have a problem with my advertisements on the domain www.spiceygames.com (this site's using innovation science 2 (cms) theme from themeforest). Take a look on the main page, below slider my adsense advertisements are displayed.

These ads are actually from single posts, I'll add them via quick adsense plugin and they're working fine on single post.

The problem is on the main page,single posts ads are also displayed in main page, I didn't want to show them on the main page. I think there's some bugs in css/theme files. So how do I fix it?

```
<?php
/**********************************************************************
* INNOVATION SCIENCE WORDPRESS THEME  
* (Ideal For Business And Personal Use: Portfolio or Blog)   
* 
* File name:   
*      single.php
* Brief:       
*      Theme single page code
* Author:      
*      DigitalCavalry
* Author URI:
*      http://themeforest.net/user/DigitalCavalry
* Contact:
*      digitalcavalry@gmail.com   
***********************************************************************/ 
get_header();        

$catlist = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
$catlist = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'category');
$count_cat = count($catlist);

$extname = array();
if($count_cat > 0)
{       
   foreach($catlist as $cat)
   {
       $extname[$cat->name] = get_category_link($cat->term_id);
   } 
}   

if(!isset($_SESSION[('pv'.$post->ID)])) { $_SESSION[('pv'.$post->ID)] = false; } 
if(isset($_SESSION[('pv'.$post->ID)]) and $_SESSION[('pv'.$post->ID)] == false)
{   
    $post_visits = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_visits', true);
    if($post_visits == '') { $post_visits = 0; } else { $post_visits++; }
    update_post_meta($post->ID, 'post_visits', (int)$post_visits);
    $_SESSION[('pv'.$post->ID)] = true; 
}                                                 
?>

<!-- google_ad_section_start -->
<div id="content">            
    <?php 


        $post_common_opt = $GLOBALS['dc_postcommon_opt'];            
        $post_custom_content = (bool)$post_common_opt['post_custom_cbox'];
        $post_fullwidth = (bool)$post_common_opt['post_fullwidth_cbox'];

        if($post_custom_content and $post_fullwidth)
        {
            echo '<div class="page-width-full">';        
        } else
        {
            GetDCCPInterface()->getIGeneral()->includeSidebar($post_common_opt['page_sid'], $post_common_opt['page_sid_pos']);

            if(GetDCCPInterface()->getIGeneral()->getSidebarGlobalPos($post_common_opt['page_sid_pos']) == CMS_SIDEBAR_RIGHT)
            {
                echo '<div class="page-width-left">';                              
            } else
            {
                echo '<div class="page-width-right">';     
            }
        }      
        dcf_naviTree($post->ID, 0, '', $extname);         

        if($post_custom_content)
       {
            the_content();    
        } else
        {           
            GetDCCPInterface()->getIRenderer()->renderBlogPostFull();
        }

        if('open' == $post->comment_status)
        {
            echo '<a name="comments"></a>';
            comments_template();
        }
    ?>
```

Note - I'll insert advertisements by using Quick adsense wordpress plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you using as a home page? a page/custom template/index page? You can add a conditional block to your adsense code to show it to all the pages except the homepage, like so:

```
<?php if ( ! is_home() ) {?>
   <!--Ads1-->
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Ilich Thanks for your response.It is a static page,it is on wordpress cms.Follow the link and you'll undertsand http://themeforest.net/item/innovationscience-2-advanced-wordpress-theme/93906. But i didn't understand where to put this code (<?php if( ! is_home() ) {?>  ,i mean can i add it to my single.php or home.php ???

Comment: Add it to your home.php (edit: where your <!--ads9--> line is located), if that is the file being loaded, double check that you are not using a regular page as a home page.